# linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, upgrade, dpkg

I tried to install Jupyter Notebook from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jupyter-notebook-to-run-ipython-on-ubuntu-16-04) but sadly get this error.

how to fix it?

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic (4.15.0-65.74~16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic (4.15.0-65.74~16.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sort", line 6, in <module>
    from sort import cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sort.py", line 3
    print('This is suroegin's package - sort')
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already uesd:

```
sudo apt-get -f install    
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Jupyter Notebook for Python 2.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847263/install-jupyter-notebook-for-python-2-7) The accepted answer also contains commands for installing Jupyter for Python 3.x.

Comment: frist of all, thank you for your help. I am working with python 2.7.12, the output:  `def cli():
    print('This is suroegin's package - sort')
`

Comment: for jupyter, when I use the command in terminal : `jupyter notebook `, the output: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/redhwan/.local/bin/jupyter", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.command import main
ImportError: No module named 'jupyter_core'
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

- Open /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sort.py
- Go to line 3
- replace `print('This is suroegin's package - sort')` with

  `print("This is suroegin's package - sort")`
- Rerun the command you ran

Comment: thank you so much, it is fine now

Comment: how to fix this problem also, >>>>jupyter notebook:`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/redhwan/.local/bin/jupyter", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.command import main
ImportError: No module named 'jupyter_core'`

Comment: @REDHWANAL-GABRI try pip install jupyter-core

Comment: sadly, it does not work, I did it

Comment: try `pip install jupyterlab`

Comment: I tried but not works.