# How do I re-install a ca-certificates after removing it in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, certificates

First of all, I got this error, `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` because of some problems in package ca-certificates. Then finding [this](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/) blog, it mentioned some methods.
I used the first three methods.

After that, I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate) question and tried to use its answers to fix my issue but fail. Sadly, third method " `sudo apt-get --purge remove ca-certificates`, I guess that it removes every file `.crt`.

When I follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/94861/987120) answer

The output: `sudo cp foo.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/foo.crt` is `cp: cannot stat 'foo.crt': No such file or directory`

No output for : `locate foo.crt`

More information about the system:

The output:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux redhwan 4.15.0-101-generic #102~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 11 11:38:16 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The output:

```
~$ lsb_release -crid
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

The output:

```
~$ grep ' ' /etc/ca-certificates.conf
# This file lists certificates that you wish to use or to ignore to be
# installed in /etc/ssl/certs.
# update-ca-certificates(8) will update /etc/ssl/certs by reading this file.
# This is autogenerated by dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates.
# Certificates should be installed under /usr/share/ca-certificates
# and files with extension '.crt' is recognized as available certs.
# line begins with # is comment.
# line begins with ! is certificate filename to be deselected.
!This is suroegin's package - sort
```

Then removed `!This is suroegin's package - sort`

The output:

```
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up ca-certificates (20190110~16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20190110~16.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
W: /usr/share/ca-certificates/This not found, but listed in /etc/ca-certificates.conf.
W: /usr/share/ca-certificates/is not found, but listed in /etc/ca-certificates.conf.
W: /usr/share/ca-certificates/suroegin's not found, but listed in /etc/ca-certificates.conf.
W: /usr/share/ca-certificates/package not found, but listed in /etc/ca-certificates.conf.
W: /usr/share/ca-certificates/- not found, but listed in /etc/ca-certificates.conf.
W: /usr/share/ca-certificates/sort not found, but listed in /etc/ca-certificates.conf.
sed: can't read This is suroegin's package - sort: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates
```

and

```
~$ echo -e "4\n1\n3\n2" | sort
This is suroegin's package - sort
```

and

No output: `sudo updatedb`

and

```
~$ locate suroegin
/etc/ssl/certs/This_is_suroegin's_package_-_sort.pem
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179098/linux-image-4-15-0-65-generic-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-cod

Comment: No, it didn't help me

Comment: solved, https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates/+question/691169